# NavigationSplitView default sidebarToggle's size when windowToolbarStyle is unifiedCompact

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I am trying to create a UI similar to Xcode using `NavigationSplitView`, but the height of the toolbar is taller than in Xcode.

[image: as shown in this]

So I added the `.windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact(showsTitle: false))` property to the `WindowGroup`, which made the heights consistent, but the buttons in the toolbar became smaller.

[image: as shown in this]

So how can I set it to restore the buttons in the toolbar to their original size?

I want to achieve the same result as Xcode, with a narrower toolbar, but I don't want the buttons in the toolbar to become smaller. I want them to remain the same size as before.

Answer (score 0):

i find a way

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ThreeSideViewerApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .all

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $show)
            {
                Text("SideBar")
                    .toolbar(removing: .sidebarToggle)   // remove default add
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            // add my self
                            Button(action: {
                                       // use animeatino to toggle
                                       withAnimation {
                                           if show == .all {
                                               show = .detailOnly
                                           } else {
                                               show = .all
                                           }
                                       }
                                   },
                                   label: {
                                       // set large
                                       Image(systemName: "sidebar.leading").imageScale(.large)
                                   })
                        }
                    }
            }
            detail: {
                Text("detail")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your own solution! It would be helpful for future readers if you provide a short description of what you did to solve the question.